# error install mysqlclient command pip install mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, pip

error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have this error when trying to install MySQLCorn, I already have the VS builds, the updated Microsoft C++ versions installed but I still can't fix the problem

pls help

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward, this error appears every time I install `mysqlclient` on a new machine. The possible reason for this error is Mysql server doesn't exist in your system. A quick resolution for this error would be the installation of a Mysql server. To install Mysql-server visit this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/windows-installation.html)